# github workflow failed after renaming repository : links does not exists

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages

I changed the name of my github site repository :
from `username.github.io` to `lastname.github.io`

I've changed the remote origin and pushed to the repository to trigger the workflow.
The workflow failed ! Looks like he can't access any of the site files after renaming the repository.
How can  i solve this ?

[image]

Comment: Did you also change your GitHub username? The user repo (when not using a custom domain with a `CNAME` file) has to be named `USER.github.io` where `USER` is your GitHub username.

Comment: Your building your site like `bundle exec jekyll b -d "_site${{ steps.pages.outputs.base_path }}"` but your link check runs against the _site folder. Are you sure that you're build output goes to the _site folder?

Comment: @Christian I think there is an error in the destination according to workflow logs. After changing the name of the repository the destination became : Destination: /home/runner/work/username.github.io/username.github.io/_site/username.github.io instead of       Destination: /home/runner/work/username.github.io/username.github.io/_site. how can i solve this ?

Comment: So your _site folder has moved and _site respectively `/` is invalid now. One option would be to change the user names, see Benjamin's comment, the other would be to adjust the path htmlproofer checks.

Comment: You probably have changed the repo name so it does no longer match the GitHub username. This make your site appear at `USER.github/io/REPO`, where `USER` is the GitHub username, and `REPO` is the name of the repo. That's a "project site" in GitHub Pages parlance. Among other things, this requires the Jekyll `baseurl` to be set (see [this article](https://mademistakes.com/mastering-jekyll/site-url-baseurl/)). When you build with the `github-pages` gem, the [`github-metadata`](https://github.com/jekyll/github-metadata) gem takes care of this for you, but you seem to build with a workflow.

Comment: It's really quite difficult to diagnose without seeing the workflow file and repo/username configuration.

Comment: @BenjaminW. See here: https://github.com/Aliliche/Aliliche.github.io, the GitHub page deployment is also working again.

Comment: @BenjaminW. yes it works cause  I renamed the the repository as  before

Comment: @BenjaminW is there a way to change the URL of the site without changing the repo name ? im using github action not deployment from branch

Comment: Without a custom domain, it's either `USER.github.io` for the repo with exactly that name and where `USER` is your username; for all other repos, it's `USER.github.io/REPO`. If you set the user page to a custom domain name, that site will be `custom.com` (or whatever your domain is), and all projects under `custom.com/REPO` (unless you set custom domains for them separately).